# How to select any file/file path in android - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, filepicker

I have an app, and I need to choose files like PDF JSON, etc. First, I export my file, and then I can import it. To do this, I use the `file_picker` package with the below codes. Now the question is, I can pick any file's path in iOS, but on the Android side, I can not select the file or file path directly, even though I give permission in the `AndroidManifest`.

in iOS, when I trigger `pickFile()` function from the `file_picker`, it works as well. In the Android section, when I trigger the function, it opens the files, but I can not select the path or file directly. Even I can not see Flutter's application folder.

Here are the codes that I use:

```
 final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                type: FileType.custom,
                allowedExtensions: ['json'],
              );
```

Here, after getting the result I check the other conditions. Right now problem is, as I said, I can not get the file/file path from the android side specifically.

Android Manifest section:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: `Right now problem is, as I said, I can not get the file/file path from the android side specifically.` Pretty unclear what your problem is. Are you saying that the user can not select a file?

Comment: `Here, after getting the result` Well what kind of result do you get? Please tell specific value.

Comment: Sorry to hear this. Actually, the result is the selected file, and it works as well in iOS. On the other hand, since a user can not select a file in Android, I can not move further with the result variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit broad access to shared storage, target Android 11 (API level 30) or higher, **request all-files access through the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission**.

To do that after adding `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to `AndroidManifest.xml`, add **[permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)** package to your apps and Request permission like:

```
 void requestPermission() {  

await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
  
  }
```

Comment: what if the user has android 10?

Comment: what path would you save file to?